# Sending a post request with PHP from swift

Tags: php, mysql, swift, swift3

I'm trying to send a user's input (done through a UISearchBar) to my PHP file to search through a database of store names. However, it seems like my `$_POST` variable `$searchWord` is empty.

My swift code:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    if(searchBar.text!.isEmpty)
    {
        return
    }
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    doSearch(searchWord: searchBar.text!, searchbar: searchBar )

}
func doSearch(searchWord: String, searchbar: UISearchBar){

    mysearchBar = searchbar

    mysearchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/searchStore.php")

    var request = URLRequest(url:myURL! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    print("name=\(searchWord)")

    let postString = "name=\(searchWord)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

            if error != nil{
                self.displayAlertMessage(userMessage: (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            do{
                var _: Error?
                //STOPPED HERE AS OF NOW
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                self.results.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                if let parseJSON = json{
                    print("json")
                    if let stores = parseJSON["stores"] as? [AnyObject]{
                        print("stores")

                        for storeOjb in stores{
                            let name = (storeOjb["name"] as! String)
                            self.results.append(name)
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }else if(parseJSON["message"] != nil){
                        print("message")

                        let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                        if(errorMessage != nil){
                            self.displayAlertMessage(userMessage: errorMessage!)

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}

func displayAlertMessage(userMessage: String)
{
    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);
    let okAction =  UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);
    self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My PHP file

```
<?php
require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$returnValue = array();



if(empty($_POST["name"])){
    $returnValue["message"]= "Missing required field";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$searchWord =htmlentities($_POST["name"]);

$dao = new MySQLDao(Conn::$dbhost, Conn::$dbuser, Conn::$dbpass, Conn::$dbname);
$dao->openConnection();

$storeNames = $dao->searchStore($name);
$dao->closeConnection();

$returnValue["stores"]=$storeNames;
echo json_encode($returnValue);
?>

<?php
```

class MySQLDao {

```
var $dbhost = null;
var $dbuser = null;
var $dbpass = null;
var $conn = null;
var $dbname = null;
var $result = null;
function __construct($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname) {
    $this->dbhost = $dbhost;
    $this->dbuser = $dbuser;
    $this->dbpass = $dbpassword;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
}


public function openConnection() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        throw new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
    $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
}

public function closeConnection() {
    if ($this->conn != null)
        $this->conn->close();
}



public function searchStore($name){
    $returnValue =  array();
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM stores s WHERE s.name LIKE ? ";
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    if(!$statement)
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    $name = '%' .$name. "%";
    $result->bind_param("s", $name);
    $result->execute();
    $result = $statement->get_result();

    while($myrow = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $returnValue[] = $myrow;
    }

    return $returnValue;
}


}
?>
```

And `Conn.php` included MySQL connection details.

`PostString` in the swift code displays the users input correctly (I was able to figure it out by using breakpoints). However, whenever I search anything I would get an alert message saying that "Missing required field" indicating that my `$_POST` variable `$searchWord` is empty. 
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I strongly suggest using a HTTP/networking library like https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire . Building your body like that is most likely a bad idea.